# Change yii crud generated page

Tags: php, yii

I have 2 models: taxiDrivers and taxiOrders. In taxiOrders I have a field driver_id, but instead of just an id, I want to output driver's name (which is located in taxiDrivers). Both models are generated via gii, and crud tools are also generated. The page which is needed to be  changed is taxiOrders/admin (view: admin.php, models: TaxiOrders.php, TaxiDrivers.php and respective controllers)

**2 DCoder**: Thanks dude! but one more query I have and hope you can clearify: I have a standart generated admin.php view page with following code:

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'taxi-orders-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'uid',
        'did',
        'type',
        'notes',
        //'or_lat',

        //'or_lng',
        //'des_lat',
        //'des_lng',
        'cost',
        'rating',
        'date',
        'time',
        'status',

        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
and below code is for controller:public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new TaxiOrders('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['TaxiOrders']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['TaxiOrders'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

So can u please show me where I could put your manipulations.

Comment: wow guys is it so difficult? ask please if you are not understand my explanation. In other words, I want to modify output in taxiOrders admin view page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Yii way would be to define a Relation between the two model classes (and enforce it with a Foreign Key). Then Yii would know how the two classes are related and you would have an easier time loading the related data.

In the `TaxiOrders` model class, a relation would look like this:

```
/**
 *  @property TaxiDrivers $Driver
 */
class TaxiOrders extends CActiveRecord {

  // ...

  public function relations() {
    return array(
      'Driver' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TaxiDrivers', 'driver_id'),
    );
  }

  // ...
}
```

In the controller, when you load the order data, you can prefetch the associated driver data like this:

```
public function actionOrderInfo($orderID) {
  $order = TaxiOrders::model()->with('Driver')->findByPk($orderID);
  // render it
}
```

`with('Driver')` will make sure that each returned order has its driver info already loaded, no matter if you need to find one record or a lot of records. It is a lot more efficient than trying to load that related data yourself.

In the view, you can output the driver info like this:

```
echo CHtml::encode($order->Driver->Name);
```

Unless you have a foreign key to ensure data integrity, it is possible that the Driver has been deleted without clearing his existing orders... In that case `$order->Driver` will be `NULL` and the line above will cause an error. Figuring out how to avoid it should be obvious.

Comment: Thanks dude! but one more query I have and hope you can clearify: I have a standart generated admin.php view page with following code:<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
 'id'=>'taxi-orders-grid',
 'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
 'filter'=>$model,
 'columns'=>array(
  'id',
  'uid',
  'did',
  'type',
  'notes',
  //'or_lat',
  
  //'or_lng',
  //'des_lat',
  //'des_lng',
  'cost',
  'rating',
  'date',
  'time',
  'status',
  
  array(
   'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
  ),
 ),
)); ?>
and below code is for controller:

Answer (score 1):

In TaxiOrders admin use this to display driver name

```
   TaxiDrivers::getName($data->driver_id);
```

Now in the TaxiDrivers Model write a function with sql query to get the driver name like this...

```
    public function getName($getid) {
    $sql = "SELECT name  from `taxi_drivers` where `driver_id`='$getid'";
    $command=yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $rs = $command->queryScalar();
    return $rs;
    }
```

I Hope it will help you..

Comment: Not a good approach. 1) A separate query for each driver will kill page performance if used multiple times per page. 2) Building a command manually instead of using the ActiveRecord is more work for no gain. 3) Not using bind variables for dynamic input is unsafe.

Comment: Thank u for the explanation and if u could expain your commented answer in detail so that it will be very useful.

Comment: @DCoder actually atleast on a view page it is not going to kill peformance.

Comment: However I world prefer a join in query than a seperate query and more preferable Query Builder approach to make a joined statement.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj: 1) true, it's not going to kill performance on a single order view page. However, it is going to be less efficient. 2) Join in a query is exactly what my answer recommends without any need for manually writing join code.

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer Query Builder approach instead of Active record approach in joined scenarios. Like that

First Get Data through Query Builder

```
public function getTaxtOrder($id)    {
    $select = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
          ->select('to.*, td.name as driver_name')
          ->from('TaxiOrders to')
          ->join('TaxiDriver td', 'td.id = to.driver_id')
          ->where('to.id = :id', array(':id' => $id));
    return $select->queryRow();        
}
```

Then Pass through controller

```
$data = TaxiOrders::model()->getTaxtOrder($id);
$this->render('view',array(
    'data' => $data
));
```

Last use this into views

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$data,
    'attributes'=>array(
       array('label' => 'Order No', 'value' =>$model['order_no']),
       array('label' => 'Driver Name', 'value' =>$model['driver_name']),
       array('label' => 'Date', 'value' =>$model['order_date']),
    ),
));
```

This approach easily and flexibly work with multiple joined tables than Active Record Approach.